# UDF using Evaluate to write to additional cells is unpredictable

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I'm reluctant to ask questions about UDF's designed to write to other cells since, by design, this behavior is supposed to be disabled. But... I'm going to power through all the potential criticisms and ask anyway. I don't really expect to have this answered completely, so I'm just fishing for any insight into the odd behavior I'm encountering.

I have a UDF that is designed to calculate a simple bearing allowable. It takes 10 parameters. If any of the parameters are out-of-range the UDF will return "Error" in the calling cell. I wanted to one-up this rather useless feedback by listing all the offending inputs so that the user doesn't have to make a single correction one after the other. This way all the bad inputs would be listed and the user can correct all the inputs at once. FYI, there are more than 10 potential issues with the inputs due to some of the input interactions. Otherwise the user could try massaging the inputs dozens of times without success. This is why I wanted to list all the feedback at once.

The UDF: Shorthand - it sends the data to Class Module to perform all the checks and calculations.

```
public Function LBA(ByVal layup_string As String, ByVal diaBolt As Double, ByVal boltHead As String, _
ByVal eD As Double, ByVal tMetallicFitting As Double, ByVal tempF As Double, ByVal depth As Double, _
ByVal allowable_type As String, ByVal basis As String, ByVal cond As String) As Variant
    '
    ' declare variables
    Dim s As String
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim clba As New cFunc_LBA
    '
    ' send to class constructor 
    clba.init layup_string, diaBolt, boltHead, eD, tMetallicFitting, tempF, depth, allowable_type, basis, cond
    '
    ' get errors
    If clba.contains_errs Then ' ............................... check for design space violattions: errors
        s = clba.get_errs ' .................................... get concat string of all errors
        Evaluate ("post_error_messages(""" & s & """)") ' ...... run the subroutine to post err msgs
        val = "Error" ' ........................................ return value to calling cell
        '
    Else
        '
        ' return a valid bearing allowable
        val = clba.LBA ' ....................................... expose bearing allowable property
        '
    End If
    '
    LBA = val
End Function
```

The Class Module works as expected. All the calcs and error logs work. In the UDF when I check if there were errors, it returns the errors. I then send the errors (in one long concatenated string) to another subroutine that is supposed to output the errors into other worksheet cells.

The Sub:

```
Private Sub post_error_messages(ByVal s As String)
    ' declare variables
    Dim arr As Variant
    '
    ' initialize variables
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    '
    ' post error messages
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr) ' .................. loop thru error messages
        m.Cells(17 + i, 2) = CStr(arr(i)) ' ..... write msg in cell, increment by ROW#
    Next i
End Sub
```

A quirk I noticed along the way... I could only get the subroutine (called by Evaluate) to accept a single parameter. Also I could only get it to accept a simple data-type `string`. I tried `arrays`, `variants`, `scripting.dictionary` none of which worked. Hence all my error messages where concatenated into one long string then split and looped over in the sub.

My problem now is that this setup is only sort of working.

Problem 1: Regardless of how many errors are returned the Sub to post error messages will only return three items. In fact it always returns three items, even if there are only two (the last one shown gets repeated). If there are 10 error messages - 3 get shown. I put `debug.print` statements in my error message sub so I could see what was happening and it shows that when ONLY 2 error messages are returned it should only be printing to 2 cells, but it prints to the third cell anyway. More than 3 errors just get dropped.

Problem 2: If I delete the cells in the sheet showing the error messages and execute the UDF again the messages will NOT come back. Only if I close the workbook and open it again will the error message subroutine print to the cells again (from the UDF).

Also, and this is not really a problem, Evaluate runs twice. I've looked this up and it seems to be a known issue. I'm just putting this out there, but I'm not sure this causes any issues.

Again, since I'm working outside the intended functionality of Excel's UDFs I do not expect a solution. That said, can anybody offer any insight on this?

Comment: Is there a technical reason why you don't put the post_error_message functionality into the Worksheet.Calculate event? Or use a dialog to display the list of errors?

Comment: Where/how is `m` declared and poulated?

Comment: `m` is the worksheet that the udf resides. And thanks Tim, this UDF Evaluate method is directly from one of your posts.

Comment: @RichHolton I'm adding my code to someone else's workbook. There is so much in there I didn't want to bring events into the mix. Also, there was a request to post the errors to the worksheet cells. After reading Tim's post on this method I thought I'd give it a try.

Comment: Why not create another UDF, say LBA_ERROR(lbaCell as Range) that returns the list of errors associated with the LBA function in the specified cell? It could return a multi-line string, or you could add a parameter for the error line number, and have a series of cells containing calls to LBA_ERROR(). This provides flexibility in locating the error messages, and complies the Excel's restrictions.

Comment: I did not think of that. Thanks for the suggestion. That might be a more stable way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question, but this stripped-down version works OK for me:

```
Public Function LBA() As Variant
    Dim val, s

    s = "A,B,C,D,E"

    Evaluate "post_error_messages(""" & s & """)"

    val = "Error" '

    LBA = val
End Function

Private Sub post_error_messages(s As String)

    Dim arr As Variant, i

    With Sheet1.Cells(17, 2)
        .Resize(10, 1).Value = "" '<<< clear any previous errors!
        arr = Split(s, ",")
        .Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End With

End Sub
```